# How to hide pyhon selenium works for browser

Tags: python, selenium, parsing, selenium-webdriver, web

when a try to use a python Selenium, browser detect that this is a parser and i have not posibility to work with page. i can not get a page fully to make **click()** and other func.

!!! **Fake-user-agent** does not work

or pls suggest other methot to make a click on the page, for start video-player and get a link of button that located inside this player. i only need this link that always different *that is link to download a video (JW player 8.26.5 )*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### You would need to bypass the detection by the website that you're using Selenium.

One way is using `--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled` option when starting the browser. This tells the browser to not use the default user agent string, which is typically set to indicate that the browser is being controlled by automation software like Selenium.

Here is an example with chrome:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("YOUR_URL")
```

You may also need to set a custom `user-agent` string to further disguise your browser as a non-automated user:

```py
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36")
```

Comment: its also does not work , site detect the pasrer as a bot and instead video player a recieve a label with info "To protect your security, www.google.com will prevent Firefox from displaying the page if it is embedded on another site. To see this page, you need to open it in a new window."

Comment: Please note that different websites may have different mechanisms to detect a non-human user. It sounds like the website you're trying to access has implemented robust security measures to prevent automated scripts from accessing its content.

Comment: may be truth. but what i can do to bypass protection

Comment: There is no guarantee that it will work but you can try the following: Randomized wait times with `time.sleep()`, starting selenium in headless mode, configuring a proxy, rotate your user agent strings, captcha solving with OCR libraries if you need to solve captchas.